# HTML/Javascript: script src at the top in the html-file doesnt work...but why?

Tags: javascript, html

I read a bit about where to put the script `src` in the html-file. Some say at the end of the body, some say in the head. The reason is always a performance issue(because the browser will download first the script and then load the page), not that it will not working anymore at all.

But now i have a very strange behavior:

When i put it in the head or at the beginning, the javascript is not working anymore?????
When i put it before the end of the body, everything is fine.

This is my html-code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="doggos.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="tryIt">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo">huhu</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is in the **doggos.js**:

```js
document.getElementById('tryIt').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello World';
});
```

If i put the `script-src-phrase` at the end of the body my button works and the huhu transforms to Hello World. If i have the `script-src-phrase` in the head or at the beginning of the body the click on the button does not change anything (the JavaScript seems to be not available).

I am a bit confused, because these are very "simple codes" and i don't know where my fault is with the solution to put it in the head, like often recommended.

Comment: Because the HTML elements do not exist when the script is run

Comment: It's possible your script is running before the DOM has rendered your elements. See [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).

Comment: A little hack just add defer tag in script :-)

Comment: @Sanmeet that’s not a hack, but a perfectly good solution

Comment: @evolutionxbox I called it a hack since for me it seems like a trick ... I know how defer tag makes the script load after document is loaded.... 

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

The defer-"hack" was the solution. 

And especially thanks to the person, who showed me the other question, where is a big explanation for a lot of these problems :)